# Heroku Rails CORS issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, cordova, cors

I have built a rails restful service that I host on Heroku and a Angular client which I am trying to run from my local machine. Eventually this client will be run added to a phonegap project. However, for now i'm testing the application in chrome and ie and my browser keeps returning the error below.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load  Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

This is the error message that I get. I was faced with this issue before pushing to Heroku and resolved it by adding adding access headers to my responses.

```
    after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

# For all responses in this controller, return the CORS access control headers.

def cors_set_access_control_headers
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost' #*
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With X-CSRF-Token}.join(',')
        headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end
```

This does not seem to work. For some reason this isn't working with Heroku. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: did you resolved the issue? I have the same...

Comment: yep... i'll post the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery
before_filter :cors_preflight_check
after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

# For all responses in this controller, return the CORS access control headers.

def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With auth_token X-CSRF-Token}.join(',')
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end

def cors_preflight_check
  if request.method == "OPTIONS"
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With auth_token X-CSRF-Token}.join(',')
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
    render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
  end
end
end
```

That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this solution, but I do not like it. I will add below my solution.

Answer (score 6):

One of possible solutions for Rails 4 (did not check earlier versions). I used `rails-api` to create stand-alone API server. So, example based on `ActionController::API`. The same solution must work fine in case of using `ActionController::Base`.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
  include ActionController::MimeResponds

  def cors_preflight_check
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'

    render json: {} # Render as you need
  end
end


# config/application.rb
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  }
end


# config/routes.rb
# Last route definition code line
match '*path', to: 'application#cors_preflight_check', via: [:options]
```

This solution seems less hackish for me. Also, it takes care on `OPTIONS` HTTP method in "Rails-way".

Comment: Thanks Featalion, it works for me, although I do not whether it may cause some security problems. I only modified the config/application.rb file and then made a simple XMLHttpRequest from my http://localhost.

Comment: Wow, after searching for what seems like days for a solution to the general issue of CORS with heroku, I stumbled upon this, and behold! IT WORKS! Thanks, Featalion.

Comment: Works fine with Rails 5 too

Answer (score 0):

I using rails-api and this solution work for me

https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/4d7f12b213-rails-5-api-and-cors

Note: change origins 'localhost:4200' to origins '*'