# Using CORS with Rails 4 and heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, cors, assets

I'm using Rails 4 on heroku and need to enable CORS.

I've looked around the web for hours now and tried various solutions, which worked for many other people, but not for me.

My last try was to simply add CORS to all requests in the application controller:

```
before_filter :cors_preflight_check
after_filter :set_headers

def set_headers
    #if request.headers["HTTP_ORIGIN"]
      # better way check origin
      #if request.headers["HTTP_ORIGIN"] && /^https?:\/\/(.*)\.(.*)\.cloudfront\.net$/i.match(request.headers["HTTP_ORIGIN"])
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With auth_token X-CSRF-Token}.join(',')
        headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
      #end
    #end
  end

  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == "OPTIONS"
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With auth_token X-CSRF-Token}.join(',')
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
  end
```

The commented lines were a try to make all of it more clean. However, nothing of this works. This is how [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883497/heroku-rails-cors-issue) told me to do.

Do you have any idea or hint how I can get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a good question and it needs to be answered, I have been looking for several hours myself.

Comment: I'll post my solution now

Comment: I ran into this issue last night and I was not pleased!

Answer (score 2):

So you have just about everything I have but I don't think you're matching the options request to your cors_preflight_check method. You can also remove the before filter on cors_preflight request since options will be routed there by default. And if you have any authentication for requests it needs to be removed for options requests. Check this out https://github.com/cleor41/Cors-Rails4-API and I'll post the important parts here.

This goes in the application controller for your API

```
#APIController

before_action :authenticate_user
after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user, :only => [:route_options]

def route_options
  cors_preflight_check
end

private

  def authenticate_user
    #Do some cool stuff with tokens to identify the user
  end

  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Token, Auth-Token, Email'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
  end

  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS'
      request.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      request.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS'
      request.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, Token, Auth-Token, Email'
      request.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'  
      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
  end
```

This goes in your routes and matches to the cors_preflight_check in your api application controller

```
#Routes

#Route this to wherever you put the cors_preflight_check
#This is to handle the CORS preflight request, it only catches the options action.
controller 'api/v1/api' do
  match '*unmatched_route', :to => 'api/v1/api#route_options', via: [:options]
end
```

Hope this works for you, let me know if it doesnt.

Comment: This worked for me but I decided to use the rails cors gem since it doesn't pollute my application controller and I hate looking at this. I would recommend creating a cors object or something and stuffing this in there if you go this route.